# (Qt Error) Launch Houdini on linux Debian 11

Tags: linux, debian, debian-based, debian-buster, houdini

i am trying launch houdini on linux, but i get this error .

./houdini
Qt Error: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

2031:  (sent by pid 2031)
Crash log saved to /tmp/houdini_temp/crash.santifer_2031_log.txt

help me, thanks Folks

i expecting launch houdini on DebianLinux

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue on Pop_OS 22.04 running wayland. I was able to resolve it by running Houdini with the following command:

```bash
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb /opt/hfs19.5.303/bin/houdini
```

Just replace the "hfs19.5.303" with whatever version you are trying to actually run. I also just learned that as of QT5.11 you can set a fallback of x11 as well in case wayland isn't working via:

```bash
QT_QPA_PLATFORM="wayland;xcb"
```